# Ansible: How to use an Azure RM template in `azure_rm_deployment` module?

Tags: azure, ansible

I have a virtual machine ARM template built in the following way: <sup>[refernce](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-ps-template/)</sup>

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {  },
  "variables": {  },
  "resources": [  ],
  "outputs": {  }
}
```

with `parameters.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "adminUserName": { "value": "mytestacct1" },
    "adminPassword": { "value": "mytestpass1" }
  }
}
```

I can successfully deploy the machine using this template in PowerShell:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $rgName -TemplateFile VirtualMachineTemplate.json -TemplateParameterFile Parameters.json
```

However, if I try to use the same template for Ansible `azure_rm_deployment` module in the following task:

```
- name: Ensure the VM is deployed to Azure
  azure_rm_deployment:
    state: present
    resource_group_name: "{{ resource_group_name }}"
    template: "{{ lookup('file', 'VirtualMachineTemplate.json') }}"
    parameters: "{{ lookup('file', 'Parameters.json') }}"
```

I get an error:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "failed_deployment_operations": [], "msg": "Deployment failed with status code: 400 and message: The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Error converting value \"https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json\" to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Frontdoor.Data.Definitions.DeploymentParameterDefinition'. Path 'properties.parameters.$schema', line 1, position 142.'."}

---

The error is caused by `parameters.json`. If I define the parameters directly in the task:

```
- name: Ensure the VM is deployed to Azure
  azure_rm_deployment:
    state: present
    resource_group_name: "{{ resource_group_name }}"
    template: "{{ lookup('file', 'VirtualMachineTemplate.json') }}"
    parameters:
      adminUserName:
        value: mytestacct1
      adminPassword:
        value: mytestpass1
```

It deploys the machine.

I'm at loss here. Is there a modification required to the template for the Ansible module?

---

Notes:

- At the same time I can provision resources and VMs using `azure_rm_storageaccount`, `azure_rm_virtualmachine`, etc. modules, so I guess it's not a library problem; at least not the Microsoft Azure SDK for Python, which is 2.0.0rc5 per requirements.
- Just to make sure I also tried with `template_link` and `parameters_link` and the error message is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see this is rather old question, but I note that there's own field `parameters` in the parameters file, so the right call should be:

```
- name: Ensure the VM is deployed to Azure
  azure_rm_deployment:
    state: present
    resource_group_name: "{{ resource_group_name }}"
    template: "{{ lookup('file', 'VirtualMachineTemplate.json') }}"
    parameters: "{{ (lookup('file', 'Parameters.json') | from_json).parameters }}"
```